How to un-manage a resource from AWS CloudFormation Stack?
I created a resource like an S3 bucket via CDK.
For whatever reason, I now want to continue managing this resource manually. Therefore, I want to remove it from CDK and underlying CloudFormation stack, but without actually deleting the resource in AWS.
How can I do that?
I only found other people setting a DeletionPolicy of "Retain" and afterwards removing the resource from the stack. This results in the resource not getting deleted. This approach seems to be a bit risky to me.

The approach you described is indeed the correct answer.
